# Javascript if-else doesn't work

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to run the below code consisting of if statments , but i am not able to show the alert.I even tried only if but no luck. 
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <script>
        var a= "am";
        var c = 8; 
        var d = 7;

        if(a == a)
        {
            alert("1st if");
            if(c > d)
            {
                alert("2nd if");
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                alert("1st else");
            }
        } 
    </script>      
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your brackets aren't balanced, and if you press F12 in Chrome you will most likely see JavaScript errors in the console.

Comment: And what are you returning here?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't see any error or "unbalanced" brackets

Comment: try removing `return false;`

Comment: This code works for me. I get alerted "1st if" and "2nd if"

Comment: There are 3 alerts and that code will show 2 of them.  Tell us what you mean by, "I am not able to show the alert".

Comment: Can you replace the whole script with for example, just `alert("hello")`? I suspect your configuration is invalid.

Comment: You should get error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement` return can be only in a function, try to remove it.

Comment: Yes i got the alerts by removing "return false", but the reason i m using the return statement is because i use multiple if condition in my program.

Comment: Also can anybody explain why won't this work with return false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get what you are trying to do with the "return false" statement.
Anyhow, you can just remove it and the if-else will work properly.

EDIT: Note that the "return" statement should be used within a function: you can include your if statements within a function declaration or even a self-invoking anonymous function.

Here's an example that shows the alerts:

```
var a= "am";
var c = 8; 
var d = 7;
(function (){
    if(a == a)
    {
        alert("1st if");
        if(c > d)
        {
            alert("2nd if");
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            alert("1st else");
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: consider a form where you validate using multiple if's, in that case if you hit the first "if" the program should stop  instead of going to the the next ifs

Comment: The "return" statement is used inside a function to stop its execution and return a value. I added an example

Comment: Thanks for explaining it , instead of just down voting!

Answer (score 0):

Remove "return false" it will work.

Comment: Why downvote, this is the correct answer, when return is outside of function it will throw exception `Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement`